# How to force Vue to update modified HTML

Tags: vuejs2

I use a custom directive to render LaTeX-code with KaTeX' [renderMathInElement](https://katex.org/docs/autorender.html) function. This, obviously, changes the component's `innerHTML`. I would like to re-run KaTeX once the content changes, but: The content never does!

A simple reproduction of the problem does not need KaTeX or directives and still shows, that reactivity works, but stops to work for the parts of a component with changed `innerHTML`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{content}}
    <span ref="elem">{{content}}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Ref, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

  @Component({})
  export default class Test extends Vue {
    content = "Hello World!";

    @Ref()
    elem!: HTMLSpanElement;

    mounted(): void {
      // Without the following statement, Vue correctly re-renders the whole component after a second with the new content
      // With this line, the update does not happen for the span element.
      this.elem.innerHTML = "<b>Hello World!</b>";

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.content = "Greetings!";
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
</script>
```

I suppose this is intended behavior - but that doesn't solve my problem. Is there some way to force Vue to replace all the component's DOM as soon as a re-render takes place?

Comment: Does this help? https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: Only if I give the `span` a key that matches its content to force Vue to replace the span. This, however, becomes unpractical once slots and similar nested Component concepts come into play (which is the case in my project): It doesn't seem to be a good idea to pass the complete sub-content as key to the topmost element with the katex-directive.

Comment: What about the `forceUpdate()` solution? (In the same link)...also I don't suppose it's possible for you to use `v-html`, is it? That would probably maintain reactivity

Comment: Doesn't do anything new - which is kind of logical, given that a re-render already does take place (the content outside the span *is* updated, but just not of the whole DOM inside the component).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use a `key` on your span, but if you don't want to tie it in with `content`, you can instead set it to a number, and increment it every time you want to make a change. Like so (I am not using TS here):

Set a `key` on your span:

```
<span :key="content_key">{{ content }}</span>
```

Then you can watch `content` and update the key accordingly:

```
watch: {
    content() {
        this.content_key ++;
    }
}
```

In this way you can avoid setting the `key` to `content` directly.

[image]

Does this work for you?

Comment: Not pretty, but I guess vue doesn't really allow for something better. Thanks for your idea!